# Unable to select System Image in Android Studio

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

[image: photo of android studio]

I am facing a problem while installing android studio [first time installing], i was selecting virtual device but i was not able to select the System image , how can i fix it , i was doing that because there was no virtual device installed option in android studio

Comment: Click the download button (next to the release name), post successful download the record will be available to be selected

Comment: ok let me do this @PradeepKumar , i will make an update here soon

Comment: @PradeepKumar, can you tell how can i install AVD [android virtual device] because i was getting an recommendation when i was installing Android studio, that AVD is not installed.

Comment: That can be installed at a later stage. Lets finish this setup now.

Comment: @PradeepKumar , its getting download , i have selected Android 13.0 [top most]

Comment: Once its downloaded, you will be able to select the record.

Comment: I already done that @PradeepKumar , thanks

Answer (score 1):

please download before select OS API, check below image

[image]